# Надо сделать так как на изображении

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, как это сделано, блоки над друг другом стоят, кто знает подскажите пожалуйста

вот структура

```html
<ul id='headlines' class='news short'>
  <li>
    <div class="title">
      <h2>First block</h2>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Second block</h2>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Third block</h2>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Читай про свойство `position`. Есть `static`, `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`. Это поможет разобраться в этом вопросе. Ничего сложного.

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простой примерчик, ну и как тебе посоветовали выше почитай про позиционирование элементов. В данном примере используется абсолютное позиционирование:

```css
.container div {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
.container div:nth-child(1) {
  background: yellow;
  top: 10px;
  border-color:green;
  color: green;
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  border-color: black;
  color: black;
}
.container div:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
  top: 90px;
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>First block</div>
  <div>Second block</div>
  <div>Third block</div>
</div>
```